# find word in a text in C++ and print some next specific lines

Tags: c++, io

I wrote a code in C++ that writes a .txt file.
Then I want to open the code again and give some information, so I can get a new text depending on what I gave as an input.
For example I want to give the name of a month, and print in another .txt file all the lines that came after the word "November".
I found some solutions, but none of them worked for me!

One solution that I found on stack overflow is the following:

```
void Keyword(ifstream & stream, string token) {
    string line;
    while (getline(stream, line)) {
        if (line.find(token) != string::npos) {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << token << " not found" << endl;
}
```

I can't print the next lines with the code above.

Any suggestion would be helpful!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes you're right. edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform operations on files such as 'Read' and/or 'Write',you might want to search on the net(or if you have a C++ book) on topics such as "File I/O operations using C++". Anyways moving on, C++ has 2 basic classes to handle files which are `ifstream` and `ofstream`. And to use them you have to include ethier the header `fstream`(i.e `#include<fstream>)` or include them separately as `#include<ifstream>` and `#include<ofstream>`. `ifstream` is basically used for all input operations such as reading files etc. Similarly `ofstream` is used for all output operations such as writing data to files.

You can open a file and write data to it by doing the following,

```
ofstream myFile("filename");// Create an instance of ofstream and open file for writing data
```

and to write data to the file use the `<<` operator like below,

```
myFile<<data;
```

Similarly, You can open a file and read data as follows,

```
ifstream myFile("filename");//Create an instance of ifstream and open file to read data
```

and to read data from the file use the `>>` operator as shown below,

```
myFile>>data;
```

You can also open a file using the method `void open(const char *filename, ios::openmode mode);` as shown below,

```
//Writing only
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("filename.txt",ios::out);


//Reading only 
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("filename.txt",ios::in);

//For reading and writing
fstream file;
file.open("filename.txt",ios::in|ios::out);


//For closing File
outFile.close();
//or
inFile.close();
//or
file.close();
```

Note the `open()` method takes various flags such as `ios::in` for reading mode, `ios::out` for writing mode, `ios::app` for adding data to the end etc.
All of these can also combined by using the bit OR operator `|` as shown below,

```
outFile.open("filename.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
```

There is a lot more in IO. I just covered the things required to start.

Here is the solution to your problem. Try to understand it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;



int main()
{ 
  ofstream outFile;
  ifstream inFile;
  char fileName[10],data[50];
  int noLines;

 cout<<"Enter Month:"<<endl;
 cin>>fileName;
 cout<<"Enter Number of lines you want to enter:"<<endl;
 cin>>noLines;

 outFile.open(fileName,ios::out);
 cout<<fileName<<"(Enter Data):";
 for(int i=0;i<=noLines;i++)
 {
  cin.getline(data,50);
  outFile<<data<<endl;
 }
 outFile.close();

 cout<<"Openening "<<fileName<<" :"<<endl;
 inFile.open(fileName,ios::in);
 for(int i=0 ;i<=noLines ;i++)
 {
  inFile.getline(data,50);
  cout<<data<<endl;
 }
 inFile.close();



 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The first half of this answer is not bad, not well targeted to the OP's question, but not bad. The second half earns it a downvote. It doesn't do what the OP needs and it's doing downright dangerous stuff with the char arrays.

Comment: Yeah damn it's got to be getline(data,50). I forgot that I changed it back to 50.

Comment: They shouldn't be `char` arrays in the first place. Unless you have a reason to use a `char` array in place of a `string`, use the `string`. Almost all reasons to use a `char` array are artificial at this point, ancient API that can't handle a `const char` array or instructor fiat, so use the `string`. Second, while this reads the file back in, it doesn't do the part that has  OP stumped: print out only lines after the keyword. is found.

Comment: Dude it's just an example. It's not like it's going to be actually implemented in some real time scenario. I was just focusing more on how to proceed with a solution rather than worrying about which standard/mechanism is better and all. Those all things can be later decided by him. Besides if he wanted backwards compatibility with C it's better to go with Char's. But, I agree with you that 'string' is the way to go in C++ if you aren't worried about backward compatibility or legacy C code.

Comment: Also the method open() doesn't take C++ string(Unless  it is C++11) it takes C type strings.

Answer (score 0):

OP has found most of the solution already:

```
string line;
while (getline(stream, line)) {
    if (line.find(token) != string::npos) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
cout << token << " not found" << endl;
```

But this only prints the lines with the keyword. And always prints the "not found" message. Ooops.

Instead I pitch:

```
string line;
bool found = false;
while (!found && getline(stream, line)) 
{ // search for keyword
    if (line.find(token) != string::npos)  
    {
        found = true; // found keyword. Stop looking
    }
}
if (found)
{ // print out all remaining lines in the file
    while (getline(stream, line)) 
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << token << " not found" << endl;
}
```

The above splits the finding of the token and the printing of the remaining file into two stages for readability. It can be compressed into one loop, but two things make this a sucker bet:

1. this program will be IO bound. It will spend the vast majority of its time reading the file, so little tweaks that do not address getting the file into memory are wasted time.
2. combining the loops would require the addition of logic to the loop that would, over along run, dwarf the minuscule cost of switching loops.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
and this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14975/

It's about reading and writing files in c++ and about searching in files.

Comment: Links aren't answers, and besides that it is _far_ better to learn C++ from a good, peer-reviewed book than random "tuts" on the internet.